# Logging connections on a port of a openvz container by iptables

Tags: iptables, openvz

I'm trying to log the connections that are made on the container with the IP x.x.x.x

I'm sending an email using postfix by the mail command but I don't see any logs.

Here is my configuration:

> iptables -N LBFT_OUT
>   iptables -A FORWARD -j LBFT_OUT
>   iptables -A OUTPUT -j LBFT_OUT
>   iptables -A LBFT_OUT -s x.x.x.x/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -m state --state NEW -j LOG --log-prefix "LBFT_SMTP " --log-level 7
>
> [root@host log]# cat /etc/rsyslog.d/lbft.conf
>   :msg, contains, " LBFT_SMTP" -/var/log/lbft-smtp.log
>   & ~

Answer (score 2):

It seems iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp --dport 25 -o eth0 -m state --state NEW -j LOG --log-level info --log-prefix 'LBFT_SMTP ' works.

Comment: This is accurate, as in host-routed mode containers' traffic goes via FORWARD, not INPUT/OUTPUT chains